# Serverless Framework + Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, serverless

I'm running into issues with connection and disconnecting to my Neo4j database using the Serverless Framework. In the Neo4j docs, it shows this code in the [JS section](https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/#javascript-driver):

```
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')

const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password))
const session = driver.session()
const personName = 'Alice'

try {
  const result = await session.run(
    'CREATE (a:Person {name: $name}) RETURN a',
    { name: personName }
  )

  const singleRecord = result.records[0]
  const node = singleRecord.get(0)

  console.log(node.properties.name)
} finally {
  await session.close()
}

// on application exit:
await driver.close()
```

I run into issues with this code for a couple reasons. In my lambda function, if I run just this code I'll get the error:

`Pool is closed, it is no more able to serve requests`

If I move the `driver.close` into the finally, I'll get this error:

`Neo4jError: Cannot begin a transaction on a closed session.`

To be clear, I can make one successful request to the database then the second will fail.

I had this issue when using `pg-node` with postgres + serverless. I fixed the issue by using [the serverless-postgres npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-postgres).

It seems that maybe I need to not use the driver and instead make simple HTTP request like [the docs here](https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/#js-http-endpoint). Interested in opinions on how to move forward.

Comment: Is that the exact code that you have in your lambda? i.e. the body of your handler function? then it should work, if some of it is outside of the handler, you need to accommodate for drivers not surviving lambda executions if they are recycled.

Comment: @MichaelHunger sorry for the delayed response, life happened. I'm currently using the solution below where I create an instance in every lambda execution. Not calling "driver.close()" at all is working as intended. I have a "maxConnectionLifetime" of 1 minute since that's all the lambda should need really. If I run driver.close() I'll get a "poll is closed" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using Lambda, but I believe for any JS runtime the same rules would apply.
In the example below, included some of the driver's option for you to tweak and see what combination works for your scenario.

Can you try:

```js
import { driver, auth } from 'neo4j-driver';
import { config } from 'dotenv';

/**
 * Read environment variables (for test-bed)
 */
config();

/**
 * Singleton for Neo4j Connection Driver
 */
const neo4j = driver(process.env.NEO4J_URI, auth.basic(process.env.NEO4J_USER, process.env.NEO4J_PASSWORD),
  {
    maxConnectionLifetime: 10 * 60 * 1000, // 10 minutes
    maxConnectionPoolSize: 300,
    encrypted: process.env.NEO4J_ENCRYPTION || "ENCRYPTION_ON",
    trust: "TRUST_ALL_CERTIFICATES",
    // trustedCertificates: [process.env.NEO4J_TRUSTED_CERTS],
    logging: {
      level: 'debug',
      logger: (level, message) => console.log('+++' + level + ' ' + message)
    }
  });


/**
 * Wrapper to execute cypher queries using session from pool 
 * and automatic transaction management (commit, rollback, session closing)
 * @param {*} query Cypher statement(s) 
 * @param {*} params Query params 
 * @returns Promise<Record<Dict, PropertyKey, Dict<PropertyKey, number>>[]>
 */
async function runNeo4jQuery(query, params) {
  const session = neo4j.session();
  let result;

  try {
    const transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    try {
      result = await transaction.run(query, params);
      await transaction.commit();

      return result.records;
    } catch (error) {
      await transaction.rollback();
      throw error;
    }
  } finally {
    await session.close();
  }
}

async function main() {
    let results = [];

    const statement = `CREATE (a:Person {name: $name}) RETURN a`

    let params = {
        name: 'Alice'
    }

    results = await runNeo4jQuery(statement, params);
    console.debug(results);
}

(async function () {
    await main();
})().catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
    process.exit(1);
}).finally(async () => {
    await neo4j.close();
    process.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, life happened. Creating a session for each lambda instance, instead of just once outside the lambda (like the driver), is now working properly on my end. I was expecting to need to close the driver connection by running "driver.close()" in the "finally". How come you don't do that? Is it not necessary?

Comment: @user2465134 yes, you should call `driver.close()`

The session, you close once you are done with your interactions with the DB so that the underlying connection can be released to the connection pool making it available for other clients. 

The `driver.close()` will close all open sessions and other associated resources. 
If you are sure that your code can always hit that call, you could use only `driver.close()` as it will close any open session and terminate other resources that might  be still in use.

NOTE: I've updated the sample I had provided to also call `driver.close()`